# Solving third-order ordinary differential equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, functions

What is the general way of solving third-order differential equation of the following form?
$\frac{\partial y^3}{dx^3}=f(x)y$, where f(x) is an analytic function of x, e.g., $f(x)=sin(x)^m, \frac{x^m}{1+x^n}$, where $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$. The given boundary conditions are $y''(0)=y'(0)=0.$
I would like to have analytical solution, or approximate solutions at some $x-$limits. Any direction toward solving the equation is appreciated.

Comment: If $f(x)$ is a monomial, i.e. $f(x) = x^n$, you may use a series expansion.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But if it is in the form $f(x)=\frac{x^m}{1+x^n}$, that may be written as $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n x^m x^{n}$, then using series expansion would be bit problematic as the series may not have any closed form. Is there any other method to solve such problem? thanks!

Comment: I'll think about it. However, I'm not aware of a general method to solve such differential equations and I'm afraid there is none.